# I am a new discord.py user attempting to make an 8ball command embeded

Tags: bots, discord.py

I have made an 8ball command for my discord bot, but cannot figure out how to make it an embedded response. Before I tried to make it an embed, my code worked with

```
await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')
```

Now I've tried to make an embedded 8ball and when I try it, the bot doesn't respond. Here's my code.

```
@bot.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
  responses = [
  discord.Embed(title='It is certain.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='It is decidedly so.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Without a doubt.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Yes - definitely.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='You may rely on it.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='Most likely.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Outlook good.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='Yes.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='Signs point to yes.'),
    discord.Embed(title='Reply hazy, try again.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='Ask again later.'),
    discord.Embed(title='Better not tell you now.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='Cannot predict now.'),
    discord.Embed(title='Concentrate and ask again.'), 
  discord.Embed(title="Don't count on it."), 
  discord.Embed(title='My reply is no.'),
    discord.Embed(title='My sources say no.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='Outlook not very good.'), 
  discord.Embed(title='Very doubtful.')
    ]
  responses = random.choice(responses)
  await ctx.send(embed=f'Question: {question} \nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embed parameter in `ctx.send()` can only contain a discord embed object, while yours contains a string. Instead, you can send strings through the content parameter.

Aside from that, you also called `random.choice(responses)` twice. The first time you used it returns a random embed object from a list, and the second one tries to return a random object from something that is not a list, which would raise an error.

Try this instead:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
  responses = [
  discord.Embed(title='It is certain.'),
  discord.Embed(title='It is decidedly so.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Without a doubt.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Yes - definitely.'),
  discord.Embed(title='You may rely on it.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Most likely.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Outlook good.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Yes.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Signs point to yes.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Reply hazy, try again.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Ask again later.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Better not tell you now.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Cannot predict now.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Concentrate and ask again.'),
  discord.Embed(title="Don't count on it."),
  discord.Embed(title='My reply is no.'),
  discord.Embed(title='My sources say no.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Outlook not very good.'),
  discord.Embed(title='Very doubtful.')
    ]
  responses = random.choice(responses)
  await ctx.send(content=f'Question: {question}\nAnswer:', embed=responses)
```

Comment: This worked, however, is it possible to add the Question and answer thread into the embed?

Comment: Try modifying each `discord.Embed(title='answer')` to 
`discord.Embed(title=f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: answer')`

Answer (score 0):

first you can make a json file or a list of responses.

using json.. do it like following:

create a file called `responses.json`
add values to it:

```json
{
    "possibilities": [
        'no',
        'It is certain.',
        'It is decidedly so.',
        'Without a doubt.',
        'Yes - definitely.',
        'You may rely on it.',
        'Most likely.',
        'Outlook good.',
        'Yes.',
        'add more here...'
    ]
}
```

now in your main python file:

```
import json

with open("./possibilities.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file) 
    possibilities = data['possibilities']

@bot.command(aliases=['8ball']) async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    response = random.choice(possibilities)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="8ball", description=f'Question: {question}\nAnswer:{response}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(aliases=['8b', '8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
  member = ctx.author
  responses = ['It is certain','It is decidedly no', 'Without a doubt', 'Yes - definitely', 'You may rely on it', 'Most likely', 'Outlook good.', 'Yes.', 'Signs point to yes.', 'Reply hazy, try again.', 'Ask again later.', 'Better not tell you now.', 'Cannot predict now.', 'Concentrate and ask again.', 'Donot count on it.', 'My reply is no.', 'My sources say no.', 'Outlook not very good.', 'Very doubtful.']
  resp = random.choice(responses)
  eibed = discord.Embed(title = f" | {member.name} your answer:", description = f"`Question:` {question} \n`Answer:` {resp}", color = discord.Color.blue())
  eibed.set_footer(text='ball')
  await ctx.send(embed=eibed)code here
```

Comment: @Tyler2P Yes thank you! Actually I am new here... Next time I will take care